# Why won't this expression with exp() with curve function not work?

Tags: r, curve, exp

```
curve((pi*exp^(-x))/(2), 0, 10, xlab = "x", ylab = "f(x)/g(x)")
```

> Error in exp^(-(x)) : non-numeric argument to binary operator

Comment: Because exp is a function. I don't know what you believe exp^(-x) does but it doesn't do what you believe.

Comment: How can I graph this desired expression then?

Comment: This is just a typo. The `exp()` is already a function. You don't need `^` as well. Just use `exp(-x)`, not `exp^(-x)`

Comment: maybe a misunderstanding more than a typo.  If `exp` actually meant "e" (i.e. the base of the natural log) then `exp^(-x)` would be correct. `exp(1)^(-x)`  *would* work (`exp(1)` is "e"), although it would be inefficient and possibly confusing

Answer (score 2):

The argument in the `exp` function is the power.

`exp(-x)` can be read as "e to the power of negative x"

```
curve((pi*exp(-x))/(2), 0, 10, xlab = "x", ylab = "f(x)/g(x)")
```